# Adding Items to ListView too slow in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to add item to listview control. This is a bit of code :

```
    this.lView.ListViewItemSorter = null;
    ListViewItem[] lvitems = new ListViewItem[ListMyObjects.Count];
    int index = 0;
    foreach (MyObject object in ListMyObjects)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();               
            item.Text = object.Name;
            lvitems[index++] = item;
        }
    this.lView.BeginUpdate();
    this.lView.Items.AddRange(lvitems); // Slow in here with debugger
    this.lView.EndUpdate();
```

I'm only add about 1000 item but it's very slowly. It's spend about 15secs to finish.
why does anyone know the reason ? Thank in advance.

**Edit** :

I have customized listview before.

```
public partial class MyListView: ListView
{        
    public MyListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.View = View.Details;
        this.FullRowSelect = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    private bool mCreating;
    private bool mReadOnly;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        mCreating = true;
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        mCreating = false;
    }
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return mReadOnly; }
        set { mReadOnly = value; }
    }
    protected override void OnItemCheck(ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!mCreating && mReadOnly) e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
        base.OnItemCheck(e);
    }   
}
```

I do it because i don't want to hang when i use multiple threading. I don't know what does this influenced to it ?

Comment: Which line is the slow part? (use the debugger)

Comment: I tried it with integer values, and it operates with acceptable speed. (<2seconds). Maybe it is related to your objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to speed adding items to a ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008310/how-to-speed-adding-items-to-a-listview)

Answer (score 3):

You could make it much faster by enabling [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx).
However, that will take some work.

Comment: Do you know whats the reason for that behavior? As I commented on the question, it works well for integers.

Comment: @Slaks, force garbage collector to run inside foreach loop. I think there are too many objects in memory before GC run automatically. You might need to add these lines of code: GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Comment: @BishnuPaudel: That won't do any good at all; there isn't anything to collect in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way of adding multiple items is to use the [AddRange() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfzz668s.aspx). However if you must add the items one by one you can use the [BeginUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx) and EndUpdate() methods around your loop. Following is from the MSDN

> The preferred way to add multiple items to a ListView is to use the AddRange method of the ListView.ListViewItemCollection (accessed through the Items property of the ListView). This enables you to add an array of items to the list in a single operation. However, if you want to add items one at a time using the Add method of the ListView.ListViewItemCollection class, you can use the BeginUpdate method to prevent the control from repainting the ListView every time that an item is added.

Answer (score 0):

Appologies for a more architectural solution, but if your domain objects are large this might cause the bottleneck (reading the comments it sounds like they may be slowing it down).  Before you get to the presentation layer you could flatten them into some (very simple) domain transfer objects (DTOs): literally just a bag of getters-and-setters.

A tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could potentially take a lot of the donkey work out there

That way your domain objects stay in the business logic domain (where they belong) and your presentation layer just gets the data in needs from the DTO.

Sorry for the non-code-based suggestion :) good luck!

Comment: Could you please explain how "large" objects are any different than your DTO's (=[POCO's|http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) ? The properties are just a bunch of references ?

Comment: Rant: so the comment system doesn't have a preview and I need gather more points to be able to edit/fix my own comment ? Yey ..

Comment: A DTO sends just as much data as is necessary to support a dependent system, whereas a POCO might contain a bunch of other data as well.  Generally a POCO is used within a system, a DTO is used between two systems (a system being a physical entity or a logical one).  Hope that helps, sorry the comments system is giving you grief.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, but that's only relevant if your data has to be serialized and deserialized ? Looping over a list of objects isn't going to be any slower for large objects. It's just a list of references!

Comment: It depends on what's in there - if the domain object is 10 ints, 69 strings, 12 doubles and 49 complex objects then compacting it into a DTO might be worthwhile. If it consists of one get/set int then presumably not :) +1