How to get rid of Infinite for loop to find pixel colors?
I have written the code given below to get RGB value of each pixel which belongs to a image uploaded from a file. Then i want to list all color values of every pixels in the listbox. But "for" loop goes into infinite loop so there is nothing in the listbox.
 int R, G, B, xi, yi, xf, yf;
       
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     listBox1.Items.Clear();
     if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Lütfen bir JPEG resmi yükleyin.");
         return;
     }
     Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

     xi = 0;
     yi = 0;
     xf = bmp2.Width -1; 
     yf = bmp2.Height -1;

     if (xi >= 0 && yi >= 0 && xf < bmp2.Width && yf < bmp2.Height)
     {
         for (int x = xi; x <= xf; x++)
         {
             for (int y = yi; y <= yf; y++)
             {
                 Color pixelColor = bmp2.GetPixel(x, y);

                 R = pixelColor.R;
                 G = pixelColor.G;
                 B = pixelColor.B;

                 listBox1.Items.Add($"Xi: {x}, Yi: {y}, R: {R}, G: {G}, B: {B}");
             }
         }

         // "test line" 
         listBox1.Items.Add("test line");
     }


 }

I tried taking the command to add listbox1 ouf of inner loop. I have only seen one single pixel and its RBG values. It was x:0 and y:0

I doubt that this is an infinite loop, but depending on the size of the bitmap, it might well take a while. What are the dimensions of the bitmap? If listBox1.Items.Add is the bottleneck, this question might give you some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008310/how-to-speed-adding-items-to-a-listview

You need to use pagination techniques to overcome this problem.
Your loop is not as slow as you think, it is actually super-fast.
The problem is with 'ListBox1.Items.Add' which is not designed to hold so many values you put into it, so after it get filled with few thousands of entries each additional entry take lots of time due to additional memory reallocation.
I assume you are using winforms, here is an example as to how you can work this out with DataGridView which support pagination instead of using a listbox.

using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> arr = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
            dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded;
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object? sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < arr.Count)
                e.Value = arr[e.RowIndex];
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this);
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int R, G, B, xi, yi, xf, yf;

            if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Lütfen bir JPEG resmi yükleyin.");
                return;
            }
            Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

            xi = 0;
            yi = 0;
            xf = bmp2.Width - 1;
            yf = bmp2.Height - 1;

            arr = new List<string>();
            
            if (xi >= 0 && yi >= 0 && xf < bmp2.Width && yf < bmp2.Height)
            {
                for (int x = xi; x <= xf; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = yi; y <= yf; y++)
                    {
                        Color pixelColor = bmp2.GetPixel(x, y);
                        R = pixelColor.R;
                        G = pixelColor.G;
                        B = pixelColor.B;
                        arr.Add($"Xi: {x}, Yi: {y}, R: {R}, G: {G}, B: {B}");
                    }
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.RowCount = arr.Count;
        }
    }
}

And here is another approach in case you don't really want to retain a "model" of the data which is the arr and just want to browse the pixels values:
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Bitmap bmp2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
            dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded;
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object? sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < bmp2.Width*bmp2.Height)
            {
                var x = e.RowIndex % bmp2.Width;
                var y = e.RowIndex / bmp2.Width;
                Color pixelColor = bmp2.GetPixel(x, y);
                var R = pixelColor.R;
                var G = pixelColor.G;
                var B = pixelColor.B;
                e.Value = $"Xi: {x}, Yi: {y}, R: {R}, G: {G}, B: {B}";
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this);
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Lütfen bir JPEG resmi yükleyin.");
                return;
            }
            bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            dataGridView1.RowCount = bmp2.Width * bmp2.Height;
        }
    }
}


I agree with Klaus - your loop conditions look good, but on any reasonable bitmap, this is going to take some time depending on how efficient the code behind "listbox" is.
The usual procedure for debugging loops is to put a piece of very lightweight code into the loop or into each loop ; you have two nested loops here, so put a report in at each level of the loops. Make sure that you can tell which line of code is being activated, so you can follow the progress of the loops.
My CS lecturers called such a report a "hook", with the idea that when fishing for bugs, hooks help!
If you get the first entry into the first loop reported, then it stops, then punctuate the code segments in the inner loop with further hooks, until you find where your code is hanging - or slowing to a crawl.
Does your system have a clock-time reporting function? How long does the "listbox" call take?
Another useful trick is to remember that all "for" loops can be replaced with "while", "repeat" or "do" loops (whatever your language provides) with rearranged parameters and comparisons. Rewriting them sometimes reveals flaws in your logic.
Your "xf" and "yf" variables are actually constants, and are never changed inside the loops. So, why are they appearing in your loop tests? This looks a "C"-like language, but it's not exactly clear which one of the many. Don't some of them require constants to be declared as such with a keyword?
